# Проблема с планировкой в CSS

Tags: css

При попытке добавить кнопку `<a class="button" href="#">Заполнить анкету</a>` под заголовком `<h1>Виобокс - это сервис подбора одежды для пышных женщин.</h1>` она почему-то отражается наверху страницы, а не под заголовком... Не пойму, что не так...

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #332E3C;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* HEADER ------------------------------------------------*/

header {
  background: rgb(216, 212, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(216, 212, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* border: 1px solid #708090; */
  height: 665px;
  position: relative;
}

.welcome h1 {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: 180px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.vioboxlogo {
  width: 400px;
}


/*NAVIGATION------------------------------------------------*/

nav {
  /* border: 1px solid #708090; */
  float: right;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.menu li {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 41px;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#about">О сервисе</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Как это работает</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Контактная информация</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="welcome">
      <h1>Виобокс - это сервис подбора одежды для пышных женщин.</h1>
      <a class="button" href="#">Заполнить анкету</a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="vioboxlogo" src="img/logoviobox.png" alt="Логотип Виобокс">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Как это работает?</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Скоро открытие!</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Хорошо. Выложил код. Сейчас уберу ссылку на проект

Comment: Насчёт «почему-то отражается наверху» — потому что нет ни единого стиля, которое заставило бы её переместиться вниз. Кнопка в самом-самом верху кода, заголовок h1 слева от неё из-за `float: left`, nav не считается из-за `position: fixed`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Добавляю вот это, ничего не происходит:
".button  {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 400px;
}"

Comment: Потому что для строчных элементов маргины по-другому работают, `display: inline-block` добавляйте ещё (а лучше вообще переделайте эти маргины, они страшные какие-то, почему бы не padding на `.container` повесить)

Comment: Сейчас пробую padding на .container. Что-то начало двигаться

Comment: Вроде, получилось! Спасибо! Добавил padding в контейнер и display: inline-block в кнопку